# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jakarta-ee

I am trying to show emails from gmail using javaapi.
When user clicks on the message row,the mail will open with its message body.For this I have written a javascript function:

```
function viewMail() {

    $('#table tbody').unbind().on(
            'click',
            'tr td:not(.email-select)',
            function() {

                var messageNumber = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(0)')
                        .children().val();
                var from = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(1)').text();
                var subject = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(2)').text();
                var dateAndTime = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(3)').text();
                var seen = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(4)').text();
                var folderName = $(this).parent().children('td:eq(5)').text();
                /*
                 * $.post("/Webclient/getMail", {messageId:messageId},
                 * function(data){
                 */
                var data = {"messageNumber":messageNumber,
                        "seen":seen,
                        "folderName":folderName
                        };

                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",
                    url : "/Webclient/showMail",
                    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data : JSON.stringify(data),
                    success : function(result) {
                        $('#email_subject').text(subject);
                        $('#sender_name').text(from);
                        $('#date_and_time').text(dateAndTime);
                        $('#messageBody').empty();
                        $('#messageBody').append(result.content);
                        $('#emailModal').modal('show');
                    }

                });

            });

}
```

And this in my method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showMail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String showMail(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        String emailInfo = buffer.toString();

        //This is the line I am getting error 
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(emailInfo);
        System.out.println(emailInfo);

        User authUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String userName = authUser.getUsername();
        String password = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getCredentials().toString();

        String message = null;

             try {
                message = imapService.showMail(userName,password,jsonObject);
                result.append("message",message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                result.append("message","Could not open the message");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             return result.toString();

    }
```

Error :

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
    org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:194)
    org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:321)
    controller.ImapController.showMail(ImapController.java:173)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line in the error message "A JSONObject text must begin with '{'" makes me suspect that the issue is with `emailinfo` in the `JSONObject` constructor.

I can't tell what the contents of `emailinfo` are from here, but I'm willing to bet that if you look at the contents of `emailinfo` that you print out, you'll see that `emailinfo` is not in proper JSON format.

An example of correct JSON format is something like:

```
{"key": {"second_key": "value"}}
```

Also, I recommend the following site to check if `emailinfo` is valid JSON: http://jsonlint.com

Comment: {"messageNumber":messageNumber,
                        "seen":seen,
                        "folderName":folderName
                        };

JSON.stringify(data) . This is the json string in emailInfo

Comment: messageNumber (the second appearance after the colon) needs to have quotes around it - similarly with folderName. Try out the link I mentioned, it's quite helpful!

Comment: Also, it's possible that there might be whitespace before emailinfo, or something of the sort, hence the error message about not beginning with "{". I recommend passing in `emailinfo.trim()' to the constructor in the line where you were receiving the error

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please upvote/accept! It would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message once. The problem as it turned out, was that there was an empty line just before the JSON data ie before the '{'.

Either that or some such similar issue regarding the syntax of JSON object. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to do any operation on a json which is not in a proper format, you will get the above issue. 

First try to create a new Json object with the existing json object. If you don't have any errors in the existing json you will be able to create the new. And then do your operations on the new json object.